# How do I solve an catenary arc length equation for "c"?

Tags: calculus

Would someone please give me a method for solving the following exponential equation:

> $$
> S_0 = c\left(\frac{e^{\ell /c}+ e^{{-\ell}/{c}}}{2} \right).
> $$

Comment: I don't believe this has a closed form solution in general (except for specific values such as $l=0$).

Comment: Welcome to math SE. You should typeset your equation directly instead of relying on picture. have a look at [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for your mathematical expressions